# Which UE4 class is best for storing user data in multiplayer

Tags: unreal-engine4, multiplayer

In a multiplayer environment, which UE4 class is best to store user data?

The requirements are that the data

1. has to be persistent between levels
2. has to be persistent if the actor owned by the user is destroyed
3. is *not* relevant to other users of the session. It is relevant only to the server and owner.

Because of (1) and (2), storing it on the users actor is not an option. What comes to my mind is the

- `PlayerController`, but is it persistent between levels?
- `PlayerState` with replication set to `COND_OwnerOnly` for that specific data, but is it persistent between levels?

Is there another class which better fits the requirements above?

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to answer each requirement but in an order different than the one in the question. For the third requirement, it would be best to use the `PlayerController` class over the `PlayerState` class because the player controller for a client only exists on the server and the owning client, so any information pertaining to the player controller only gets replicated from the server to the owning client. On the other hand, the player state for a client exists on the server and all the clients, so any information pertaining to the player state will get replicated from the server to all the clients, meaning that all players have access to their own and everybody else's player state.

For the first requirement, it would be best to use the `PlayerState` class over the `PlayerController` class. Note that when a level changes, both the player state and player controller are destroyed and recreated. However, with the player state, you can override the `CopyProperties` method that is responsible for copying specific information from an old instance to a new instance of the player state. Also, this will only work if seamless travel is enabled. You can read more about seamless travel [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/Networking/Travelling/index.html). You could also use the `GameInstance` class, since the game instance does not get destroyed when the map changes nor when the owning actor/pawn gets destroyed. But the game instance is only relevant to the client, so each client and even the server has their own instance of the game instance that does not get shared with anyone.

For the second requirement, instances of either the `PlayerState` or `PlayerController` class do not get destroyed/respawned when the owning actor/pawn gets destroyed/respawned. Therefore, either class will work for this specific requirement.

In conclusion, it seems that the `PlayerState` class is the best suited, because like you mentioned, when defining properties to be replicated, you can control the level at which they are replicated when you override the `GetLifetimeReplicatedProps` method and pass `COND_OwnerOnly` to a call to the `DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION` function. Here's an example of that:

```
void ACustomPlayerState::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray<FLifetimeProperty>& OutLifetimeProps) const
{
    Super::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(OutLifetimeProps);

    DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION(ACustomPlayerState, CustomProp, COND_OwnerOnly);
}
```

In addition to that, you would also override the `CopyProperties` method to "persist" specific information across map changes. Here's an example from the [ShooterGame](https://github.com/Noesis/UE4-ShooterGame) project:

```
void AShooterPlayerState::CopyProperties(APlayerState* PlayerState)
{   
    Super::CopyProperties(PlayerState);

    AShooterPlayerState* ShooterPlayer = Cast<AShooterPlayerState>(PlayerState);
    if (ShooterPlayer)
    {
        ShooterPlayer->TeamNumber = TeamNumber;
    }   
}
```

Sources for this answer as well as for more information about multiplayer concepts in Unreal Engine:

- http://cedric-neukirchen.net/Downloads/Compendium/UE4_Network_Compendium_by_Cedric_eXi_Neukirchen.pdf
- https://dq8iqaixvew1d.cloudfront.net/en-US/Gameplay/Networking/Blueprints/index.html
- https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/Networking/Actors/Properties/Conditions/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I used PlayerState in my game. And, because PlayerStates get destroyed with servertravel, I also relied on GameInstance on storing and re-loading PlayerState data before and after server travel.
I decided to relay on Unreal's framwork as a practice even if that functionality isn't there yet. So, when Epic decides to add an automated way of story player data, surely it will be the PlayerState since it is the unique aspect for each player.

Answer (score 1):

See this: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/827702/where-should-i-store-the-user-data-like-username-c.html

In short: if there is no useful information in UE docs, consider your own solution, maybe a database?